# iOS detect human face Can I know the face is inverted or normal?

Tags: ios

can I get the face is inverted or normal? I have finish to code for face detection ,

just like below:

```
// turn on/off face detection
- (IBAction)toggleFaceDetection:(id)sender
{
    detectFaces = [(UISwitch *)sender isOn];
    [[videoDataOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setEnabled:detectFaces];
    if (!detectFaces) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            // clear out any squares currently displaying.
            [self drawFaceBoxesForFeatures:[NSArray array] forVideoBox:CGRectZero orientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];
        });
    }
}
```

with apple sample code:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html

Can I know the face is inverted or normal?

I have try to get left eye position and right eye position ,mouth position ,but when the face is inverted ,the position return is not right.

The midPoint is the middle point between two eyes.
when face is upside 
the position log

```
leftEyePoistion -------------------{160, 199}
rightEyePosition ------------------{270, 262}
midPoint----------------------------------- {215, 230.5}
mouthEyePostion ---------------------------- {297, 112}
```

when face is inverted
the position log

```
leftEyePoistion -------------------{192, 200}
rightEyePosition ------------------{274, 270}
midPoint----------------------------------- {233, 235}
mouthEyePostion ---------------------------- {288, 159}
```

so I don`t think the position is right for me to make sure the face is upside or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Core Image to detect faces. Among the information you get back when a face is detected are the position of the eyes and the position of the mouth, and you can use that to determine orientation. Read more about it in the [*Detecting Faces*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_detect_faces/ci_detect_faces.html) section of the *Core Image Programming Guide*.

Comment: can I get the face is inverted or normal?

Comment: @Roy If you already have the positions of the eyes and mouth, just have a look at them. If the mouth is above the eyes, the face is upside down.

Comment: that is what I have thought ,but the position I get is not right ,no matter the face is inverted or normal ,the eyes position is always above the mouth ,so I can`t get the face orientation.

Comment: @Roy I have the same problem. Any solution?